# Crystal Reports - concatenating rows based on a field's value

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report by a dataset by two master-detail tables (For example, Organizations and Persons).
I have a group section by the master ID.
I want to show the list of the persons in each organization separated by comma in a single row instead of showing each person in a row.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how can I do it.

I added a group on `organizationID`.

Added this formula to the group's header section and suppressed it:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar Array reset;
StringVar Array names:=reset;
True;
```

Added this formula to the detail section and suppressed it:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar Array names;

Redim Preserve names[Ubound(names)+1];
names[Ubound(names)]:={persons.name_field};
```

Added this formula to the group's footer section:

```
//{@display}
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar Array names;
Join(names, ",");
```